# WCF Winform Hosting

Tags: winforms, wcf, permissions, hosting

I have a WCF service hosted in a Winforms application, it's running on a vista machine and I've used netsh to allow the application to listen on port 6003.

I have a client application which can call the WCF service when it is running on the same machine.

The problem is I cannot access the WCF service from any other PC on the network.

I've run netstat and it's definately listening on the port.

I'm using the basicHttpBinding, and it's .Net 4.

Any help would be great.

Regards

Steve

Answer (score 1):

Check the firewall settings on the PC hosting the service. It is probably blocking the access.

Comment: Agreed, check your firewall. Simply trying to telnet from a remote machine to port 6003 on the machine running the winform app will tell you if its some sort of firewall issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried hitting the services through a web browser?

You can try adding a clientaccesspolicy.xml (and a crossdomain.xml, for good measure) to the root of your server. Check the following link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: If I open a browser on another PC and point to the same wsdl I can't see it.  Would the firewall not stop the application from listening on the port?